# Default Time Interval for setNavigationBarHidden(Bool, Bool) Animation

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, nstimeinterval

What is the default time interval for Swift animations like the `setNavigationBarHidden(Bool, animated: Bool)` and `setToolbarHidden(Bool, animated: Bool)` methods of the `UINavigationController` class? I would like to know so that my animations match the same duration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/uinavigationcontrollerhideshowbarduration):

> **UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration**
>
> A global constant that specifies a preferred duration when animating the navigation bar. This variable specifies the duration when animating the navigation bar.

It is 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Perfect! The exact answer I was looking for

Comment: so what is the exact time?

Comment: @Melany it is 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @ozgur thanks a lot, but where have you found this information?

Comment: just printed that out `print(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration)`